# Sliding Panels activated by Links

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, slide

I have three links. I want each link to control a separate DIV (I guess within a container DIV). So when you open the page you have DIV-1, then you can click on the link for DIV-2 or 3 and the view will slide or scroll to that DIV.

How is this possible in jQuery? I've tried scrollleft to no avail.

Thanks in advance,

Stu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [.animate()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate) method on the margins of the first Child-Cell.

Class "cell" consists of 200x200 boxes, all floated left. ID "container" is also 200x200, with an overflow of hidden. You could assign three links to animate the margin-left of the first div having the class "cell," which would move all three left or right, depending on the amount you want.

Link1 -> First Div Margin Left = 0;
Link2 -> First Div Margin Left = -200;
Link3 -> First Div Margin Left = - 400;

---

**Update: The following code has been updated in response to follow up questions within the comments.**

I've enclosed the cells within another div. This div is within the container. Rather than manipulating the left-margin of the first cell, we're going to manipulate the left-margin of the div that these cells reside within. Give this a shot - I've tried it and Got the desired results.

```
<style type="text/css">
  div#container { width:200px;height:200px;overflow:hidden; }
  div.cells { width:600px;height:200px;}
  div.cell { float:left;width:200px;height:200px;margin:0;padding:0; }
  div.cell p {margin:0;padding:0;}
</style>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="box-mover">Show Box 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="box-mover">Show Box 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="box-mover">Show Box 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="container">
  <div class="cells">
    <div class="cell" style="background:#f1f1f1;">
      <p>Cell 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell" style="background:#cc0000;color:#ffffff;">
      <p>Cell 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell" style="background:#f1f1f1;">
      <p>Cell 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.box-mover:eq(0)").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $("div.cells").animate({"marginLeft": "0px"}, "slow");
    });
    $("a.box-mover:eq(1)").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $("div.cells").animate({"marginLeft": "-200px"}, "slow");
    });
    $("a.box-mover:eq(2)").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $("div.cells").animate({"marginLeft": "-400px"}, "slow");
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: have you got any examples? I have it so that there is 1 div, within this div it has a ul (with three links) and under this it has a containing div for the 3 divs that i want to animate. but when i click on the one i've so far got working it loses the ul. I've uploaded this to www.alwaystwisted.com/index.html

Comment: If you would like more explanation of the code, visit http://blog.sampsonvideos.com/2009/06/22/sliding-panels-with-jquery/